# For what sequences of consecutive perfect squares would the sum be a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

For example, the sum of the sequence of perfect squares from 1^2 to 24^2 = 70^2.

What other sequences (of let's say length >= 5) of some starting n^2 and ending m^2 would sum to a perfect square?

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Answer (score 0):

This is a famous problem and the answer is none. The challenge is to prove it which isn't so hard once you know the answer ahead of time. Try it.